# Rotating Android device while viewing dialog preference with TimePicker or NumberPicker causes app crash

Tags: android, android-preferences, timepicker, numberpicker, android-timepicker

I've made a custom `DialogPreference` which uses two `NumberPicker` widgets on it to allow a user to select an hour of the day as well as another custom `DialogPreference` which allows a user to select a time of day using a `TimePicker` widget.

As long as the dialog is not open and I rotate the screen, everything works as desired. However, if the dialog is open and the screen is rotated then the entire app crashes. I've placed break points in the `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` methods and have verified that everything that is needed to restore the `DialogPreference` is in order, the `onDialogClosed` method is even hit everytime along with all other custom code that I have in my custom `DialogPreference`.

I'm building with the following:

- Minimum SDK: 16
- Target SDK: 20
- Compile SDK: 20
- Build Tools: 20.0.0

I'm running Android 4.4.3 (KitKat) on a Verizon Galaxy Nexus when this is happening.

Here is the stacktrace given:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (4 ... 4) ends beyond length 0
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
  at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
  at android.text.Selection.setSelection(Selection.java:76)
  at android.widget.EditText.setSelection(EditText.java:87)
  at android.widget.NumberPicker$SetSelectionCommand.run(NumberPicker.java:2123)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22754#c5, which says the following:

> in the onCreate Method, put the following after you findviewbyId for the time picker:

```
tp.setSaveFromParentEnabled(false);
tp.setSaveEnabled(true);
```

This got rid of the error. However, the dialog doesn't stay open. But this seems to be the default functionality for all non-custom preferences, so I'm happy with it.

Here are the docs for the two methods used above:

- [`setSaveFromParentEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSaveFromParentEnabled(boolean))
- [`setSaveEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSaveEnabled(boolean))

And here are gists that I've posted of my final working custom Preferences:

- [HourOfDayPreference](https://gist.github.com/bsara/16fbed97cd7d785e2d5f)
- [TimePreference](https://gist.github.com/bsara/69c2d4aff09d7ae21b00)