# IndexOutOfBoundsException for setSpan - outside my application code

Tags: java, android

I recently published an update to my Android app and have been getting a ton of crash reports, with the following stack. I'm at a loss since there's absolutely no code of mine in the stack, so I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. Has anyone ever seen this error? Anything I can do to address this or debug it?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... 11) ends beyond length 0
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1016)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:592)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:588)
   at android.widget.TextView.setSpan_internal(TextView.java:8610)
   at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.onItemClick(Editor.java:2902)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
   at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1128)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2812)
   at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3571)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Edit: From the stack, it looks like it's going through a ListView -> itemClick -> then trying to do something with a TextView. I do have multiple clickable listViews with textViews in them... Is there a property I can set on the textViews to stop this from happening?

Comment: Is this on Android version 4.1 and 4.1.1? There is a pretty "famous" bug with spans in this Android version. Do you use any spans in your code with a MetricSpan as super class?

Comment: Android 4.2.2 and 4.4.2 so far. I don't use any Spans at all in my code (don't even know what they are...).

Comment: Looks like a EditText with suggestions enabled. See this very similar problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29508

Comment: Try this please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25880638/rotating-android-device-while-viewing-dialog-preference-with-timepicker-or-numbe

Comment: @hatem87 - stack looks different for the link you posted. Mine doesn't use NumberPicker.

Comment: @Rolfツ - looks promising, the stack is quite similar. I'll see if I can reproduce using that. Not sure about the fix though.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Were you able to solve it? Do you remember how?

Comment: I wasn't able to solve it no.

Comment: I think I'm seeing this same problem.

Comment: post codes of setting spans into the `TextView`.

Comment: Still got the same issue, even on android 8.0

Answer (score 4):

i think you have white spaces in your string you have like eleven white space string but no character so actual/trimmed length is zero, this will cause error to set selection. you can check myString.trim().lenght() > 0 before setting your selection position.

Answer (score 3):

When suggestion is used to correct the wrong word, `Editor#replaceWithSuggestion` is called, and then `TextView#setSpan_internal` and `setCursorPosition_internal` are called, but maxLength is not judged here, so it crashes.

> Thanks Ring. The following solved my issue. I extended EditText and override following methods,
>
> ```
> protected void setSpan_internal(Object span, int start, int end, intflags) {
>         final int textLength = getText().length();
>         ((Editable) getText()).setSpan(span, start, Math.min(end, textLength), flags);
>     }
>
> protected void setCursorPosition_internal(int start, int end) {
>     final int textLength = getText().length();
>     Selection.setSelection(((Editable) getText()), Math.min(start, textLength), Math.min(end, textLength));
> }
> ```
>
> From: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36944935#comment5