# IndexOutOfBoundsException setSpan (34 ... 48) ends beyond length 34

Tags: java, android

I have a crash report indicating an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` but I have no idea what caused it since there isn't anything from my code in the stack. This is the stack:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (34 ... 48) ends beyond length 34
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1265)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:684)
       at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.updateSuggestions(Editor.java:3980)
       at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(Editor.java:3833)
       at android.widget.Editor.replace(Editor.java:435)
       at android.widget.Editor$3.run(Editor.java:2359)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

The only thing I've found similar to my problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948302/indexoutofboundsexception-for-setspan-outside-my-application-code) but the guy wasn't able to solve it.

How can I know what caused it so I can look for a solution?

**EDIT**

Ok so I found in multiple parts of my large code this function being used:

```
public static Spannable spannabletext(String message, int start, int end, String font_family, Typeface font) {

    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(message));
    spannable.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(font_family, font),
            start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    return spannable;

}
```

So I'm guessing at some point this is where the problem comes from. But since I don't want to spend hours and hours trying to guess which text and in what language (my app is in 8 different languages) was this crash generated I'm going to wait till it happens again but this time I added some `Crashlytics` lines so I can get more info from the crash report. So my `spannabletext` function is like this now:

```
public static Spannable spannabletext(String message, int start, int end, String font_family, Typeface font, Activity activity) {

    Crashlytics.setString("activity", activity.getLocalClassName());
    Crashlytics.setString("message", message);
    Crashlytics.setInt("start", start);
    Crashlytics.setInt("end", end);

    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(Html.fromHtml(message));
    spannable.setSpan(new CustomTypefaceSpan(font_family, font),
            start, end, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

    return spannable;

}
```

I'll keep you posted..

Comment: share your code with question

Comment: That's the thing I have no idea what code to share since I don't know what caused it. The error was reported to me by Crashlytics. @NileshRathod

Comment: you have 34 letters in your String but you are passing more than 34 in your code, check your where you have added the SpannableString and check the String length and change code accordingly

Comment: Please share your code than I can analyze and might be help you

Comment: @RakshitNawani yup you are right

Comment: @Mauricio check the code where you are using SpannableStringBuilder

Comment: @Mauricio without snippet of code other people only guess.

Comment: ha @RatilalChopda ha

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have a similar crash where the stacktrace also contains `SuggestionsPopupWindow.show(...)` and `SuggestionsPopupWindow.updateSuggestions(...)` (which is a contrary to the issue you referenced). In my case it happend to one user two times - the user has a Galaxy S6 Edge (Android 7.0.0). I don't have a `SpannableString` (or alike) in my project, but I guess it's used as part of e.g. TextView or Webview (which I do use)?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not caused by your code. See the stack: `at android.widget.Editor$SuggestionsPopupWindow.updateSuggestions(Editor.java:3980)` that occurred when long-clicking the text to show the PopWindow. So it's a framework error, not yours.

This answer is better: [EditText crashing on clearing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749080/edittext-crashing-on-clearing-text)

> Problem is "updateSuggestions" try to setSpan after you change text in EditText. So you need make text change after editor modify EditText. Just put your code in view.post

```
mEditText.post {
   mEditText.setText("your text")
}
```

Comment: I tried it and pretty sure it doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce this crash with exactly the same stacktrace on my device. Can confirm it's really a framework issue and doesn't depend on your code. I can reproduce it in any app on my device including system apps like Messages, etc.

So what can we do:

1. Ignore it. Rare case actually, hard to reproduce, not much users should be affected. Apparently google thinks the same. Because in my crash reports I can see this issue on Android 8,9,10,11,12,13 and even the latest 14. Still not fixed.
2. Disable dictionary-based word suggestions with inputType="textNoSuggestions". It fixes the problem. But users would not be happy with this solution.
3. Wait for a fix from Google. Here's a ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314288203. There's upvote button if you're concerned about this crash.